# When and why did the beacon containing the virus get launched?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

When in the Battlestar Galactica time line did the beacon from the fake Earth that carried a form of bubonic plaque actually get launched, and why?

The way I understand it, there was a diaspora from Kobol (why?) with 13 colonies leaving to space. One got lost and made it to a fake-Earth. Fake-Earth gives rise to its own fake-Earthlings and Cylons. These Cylons nuke fake-Earth and almost wipe out the fake-Earthlings. But some scientists (the final 5) invented reincarnation and sold it to the Cylons so that they would STFU.

So questions are, where did that beacon in space that briefly infected the Cylons (with the bubonic plaque) come from? They said it was from the fake-Earth, but why was it there to begin with, and when did they deploy it?

Comment: What's with all this "fake-Earth" stuff?  _Both_ planets were Earth, neither fake.  "All this has happened before, and all this will happen again", etc, etc..

Comment: @Izkata Both of them were different planets existing at the same time. How would you name them?

Comment: Probably the same as they did in the series:  The Thirteenth Tribe's Earth, and our Earth.

Comment: I wanted to read this, but you used the prefix "fake-" so many times it became redundant and difficult to follow.

Comment: Note that the *entire population* of Original Earth was Cylon, and they left Kobol 2000 years before the humans (who forgot all about Cylons). The holocaust on Original Earth was a nuclear war between the Original Earth Cylons (the Final Five) and their centurions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Battlestar Wiki](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Lion%27s_Head_beacon):

> The beacon is apparently an artifact left by the Thirteenth Tribe as they made their way from Kobol to Earth, or possibly on a return voyage to leave a map of Earth's night sky on Kobol. It is approximately 3,000 years old.

The disease inside it was determined to be [Lymphocytic Encephalitis](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Lymphocytic_encephalitis).

Answer (score 0):

There is no fake earth, the first earth was founded by the 13th tribe where they civilized and became a prosperous and advance society just as the 12 colonies did 2000 years later. But if you go back and listen to what "Capt. Apollo" told this father after discovery another planet very similar to the first earth they found. The President was laying down plans to start building a city. But "Capt. Apollo stopped them and "No City, not this time." He said that if there is one thing that we should have learned, science has always out race there hearts in terms of technology. So the best way to break the cycle was to give up their technology which is what the 13th tribe failed to do, as well as the 12 colonies failed to do 2000 years later. They didn't learn from the past, so they were doomed to repeat it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the website! Please do take the [tour] and have a look at the [help], especially [answer]. One of our experienced community members, fez, has made a good point about not covering important parts of the question. Do you think you can add to your answer with an [edit]?